# Magento admin module using Grid and _prepareCollection: looping through the collection makes sorting fail

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento

I have made a small admin module that mirrors CMS->Page. The block for my admin page uses the code from `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Grid.php` which gives me a grid that I can sort and filter just as I can on the original CMS->Page section.

This is the code in my block for my admin page:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
        $collection->setFirstStoreFlag(true);
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Which as I mentioned displays and allows sorting correctly.

However, when I try to modify the data in the rows by amending the above with:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
        $collection->setFirstStoreFlag(true);

        foreach ($collection as $order) {
            $order->setData( 'title', 'Hello world' );    
        } 

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

I can no longer sort or filter. Can anyone shed any light on whats happening and if I have the right way of changing row data? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening: your collection is being loaded. The `foreach` language construction triggers the `load` method of your collection, and it pulls the data from the db and fill the `items`.

Why is your sorting not working? Because the sorting is applied to collection after you've loaded it already. That means that the items are already present in your collection with default sorting order.

How should you do your thing? Right now I don't know what you want to accomplish with that `setData` method for each of the collection items. If you're going to use it while creating columns, just add string value in the column.

```
...->addColumn('title', array('default' => 'Hello world'))
```

If you would want to pull some more data that is present in the collection, you don't need to load it either, just use collection methods like
`addAttributeToSelect` (if it's EAV entities) or `addFieldToFilter`.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. So how would I add to/edit the collection without reinitializing it? i.e. get at and change the data at the ->getCollection() level perhaps? I am basically trying to take the original data, add my own column, then add data to my column from my own class/method etc.

Comment: You can add the data yo your column directly omitting the collection, if you have it same for all of the items (like in your example above). Just use "default" key like I've shown in the answer

Comment: oops, I wrote "value" while it should be `default`. I've updated the answer

Comment: Would adding it in ...->addColumn(... which is in _prepareColumns() not just give every row the same value?

Comment: Sorry misread your comment. I am looking to give different values for each row, any thoughts? cheers

Comment: ok, than you need to use your logic in the `_afterLoadCollection` method of the Grid block